# What compilers can use #include <thread> or in other words, support C++ 11 that are also free?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, compiler-construction

And honestly, I would rather not go through the hassle of getting a new compiler, so is there any way to include thread in visual c++ express 2010? If not, I guess I'll just get another compiler. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope, you must get a new compiler.

Comment: What about [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread.html) ?

Comment: The first that come to mind: GCC, Clang.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, [Visual Studio 2010 only has partial C++11 support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx).

You'll need to download the (free) [Visual C++ Express 2012 or newer](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs) to get full support.

> Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2010 implemented many features in the C++11 core language specification, and Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2012 added more C++11 features. Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2013 expands this coverage even further, and also supports some select C++14 Library features. The following table lists C++11 core language features and their implementation status in Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2010, Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2012, and Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2013.

[`<thread>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh920526.aspx) is one of the "more features" added in 2012.

If you're not partial to Visual Studio, [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) (`gcc`) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) also support C++11 on Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an error "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application."

Comment: @user3376098 You got this error when doing what?

Comment: Got it after trying to launch it.

Comment: You get that error (The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)) when you use DLLs or Libs that are still compiled with VS2010. You have to recompile all your binaries.

Comment: @user3376098 Or you need to download the VS2012 version of whatever dll/lib you're linking to. (or whatever version is appropriate for the version of VS you're using)

Comment: @user3376098 "Got it" after trying to launch *what*? We don't have any idea what you are attempting to do.

Comment: @dvnrrs I got the application error after downloading VS2012.

Comment: @user3376098 Did you perhaps inadvertently get the 64-bit version but you're on a 32-bit machine?

Comment: @bames53 Any in depth tutorials on how to do that?

Comment: @dvnrrs Nope. I actually had VS2012 on my computer at one point but uninstalled for some reason(it was working fine when I had it then).

Comment: @user3376098 I've not experienced that, but a quick Google search turned up [a thread on MSDN about it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/96035692-9a50-40d4-a7d3-48bda87d11ec/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b-click-ok-to-close-the-application-when?forum=vssetup).

Comment: I have already tried everything in that thread in the past. After a lot of effort, I decided to try vs 2010. Unfortunately, it doesn't support all of c++11...

Comment: @user3376098 I thought you meant you built your program with VS2012 and then when you launched your program you got the error message. If you're saying you can't launch VS2012 then my comment has no relevance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of Visual Studio myself (although I do use it for C#) but from what I understand, Visual C++ 2013 actually does have improvements in its support for C++ 11, Have you tried downloading Visual C++ 2013 and give that a shot?

Comment: hah, ninja'd dvnrrs is correct, you can use VS just need to move up from 2010. It's not exactly like getting a new compiler, just think of it as an updated model :)